# Output all images from gallery inside a slider

Tags: gallery, slideshow

Searching in WP codex I found this function:

```
    function pw_show_gallery_image_urls( $content ) {

  global $post;

  // Only do this on singular items
  if( ! is_singular() )
    return $content;

  // Make sure the post has a gallery in it
  if( ! has_shortcode( $post->post_content, 'gallery' ) )
    return $content;

  // Retrieve all galleries of this post
  $galleries = get_post_galleries_images( $post );

  $image_list = '';

  // Loop through all galleries found
  foreach( $galleries as $gallery ) {

    // Loop through each image in each gallery
    foreach( $gallery as $image ) {

      $image_list .= '<div><img src="' . $image . '" ></div>';

    }

  }

  $image_list .= '';

  // Append our image list to the content of our post
  $content .= $image_list;

  return $content;

 }
 // add_filter( 'the_content', 'pw_show_gallery_image_urls' );
```

In the original code the return was the image URL inside a list. I adapted a little bit for create the structure I need to create a slideshow using Slick Slider.

Now I'm trying to output this function inside my single-{slug}.php to get all the images inside the gallery wrapped in a div.

I tried:

```
<div class="slider">
     <?php pw_show_gallery_image_urls( get_the_content() );  ?>
</div>
```

And:

```
<div class="slider">
     <?php pw_show_gallery_image_urls( $content );  ?>
</div>
```

The function expects one parameter, but I don't know what.

Comment: Have you tried: `<?php echo pw_show_gallery_image_urls( get_the_content() ); ?>`?

Comment: @AndyW tried now, it works, but the gallery shortcode prints too.

Comment: `do_shortcode` should do the trick: `<?php echo do_shortcode(pw_show_galler_image_urls( get_the_content() ); ?>`

Comment: not working (also add the ')' missing).

Comment: Good call on the missing parenthesis. I was also missing a "y" in the word gallery. Hope you didn't copy and paste.

Comment: Let's try that again, with the proper spelling and syntax: `<?php echo do_shortcode(pw_show_gallery_image_urls( get_the_content() )); ?>`. I find it strange that it outputs content with `echo` but not with `echo do_shortcode(...`.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so, I found this function, but it wasn't in the codex.  It came [from Pippin's Plugins](https://pippinsplugins.com/retrieving-image-urls-of-galleries/), just to clarify for any future readers.

It appears this function was used as a filter added onto the content, and will only run when filtering existing content, because it's retrieving & replacing the galleries placed inside the post content.

So, I'd recommend adding the filter back on, and not using outside of the main content, here's a reworked version of the function repurposed for your slider.

```
function pw_show_gallery_image_urls( $content ) {

    global $post;

    // Only do this on singular items
    if( ! is_singular() )
        return $content;

    // Make sure the post has a gallery in it
    if( ! has_shortcode( $post->post_content, 'gallery' ) )
        return $content;

    // Retrieve all galleries of this post
    $galleries = get_post_galleries_images( $post );

    // Loop through all galleries found
    foreach( $galleries as $gallery ) {

        $image_list = array();

        // Loop through each image in each gallery
        foreach( $gallery as $image ) {

            $image_list[] = '<div><img src="' . $image . '" ></div>';

        }

        // Append our image list to the content of our post
        if ( !empty( $image_list ) {

            $content .= '<div class="slider">' . implode('', $image_list) . '</div>';

        }

    }

    return $content;

}
add_filter( 'the_content', 'pw_show_gallery_image_urls' );
```

If this doesn't work the way you want it to, though, you might have to find a different function to start from, or write it from scratch.

Comment: Thanks, I think is better create a plugin with shortcodes or something.
Also, the link at codex could be just a reference, but the code was there: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_galleries_images#Example